# Can I completely customize the flags for ./configure in a SPEC file?

Tags: rpmbuild

My rpmbuild log tells me all the flags used when calling configure:

```
  ./configure --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu \
--program-prefix= \
--disable-dependency-tracking \
--prefix=/usr \
--exec-prefix=/usr \
--bindir=/usr/bin \
--sbindir=/usr/sbin \
--sysconfdir=/etc \
--datadir=/usr/share \
--includedir=/usr/include \
--libdir=/usr/lib64 \
--libexecdir=/usr/libexec \
--localstatedir=/var \
--sharedstatedir=/var/lib \
--mandir=/usr/share/man \
--infodir=/usr/share/info \
--prefix=/opt/custom/SENSOR/Qt-5.15.2 \
--confirm-license \
--opensource
```

My problem is that the 'build' and 'host' flags (plus several others) are unknown commands for this particular configure script. How can I take complete control of the call to configure in my SPEC file? It's obviously not enough to add new flags to the %configure scriptlet, I need to remove flags that rpmbuild is adding by default.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is to call configure directly instead of using the scriptlet. I.e., replace `%configure` with:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/custom/SENSOR -confirm-license -opensource
```